# Uninstall auto-run registry entries for all users

Tags: registry, inno-setup

**Consider this scenario:**

- Inno Setup installs program named XYZ to Program Files, to be accessed by all users.
- A configuration option within program XYZ allows installation of a registry value to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` on a per-user basis, to allow users to configure application auto-start to their own preferences.
- When uninstalling XYZ, if any user other than the current user has auto-run registry keys set, they will be left over and cause errors next time they log-in.

**Questions**

- What would be the correct way to remove the appropriate registry values from all user accounts in Inno Setup?
- Would it be appropriate to enumerate over the profiles in HKU and check for the keys and delete them? How would this be done in Inno Setup?
- Lastly, what issues might doing this cause with roaming profiles?

The program XYZ in question is in C#, and can enumerate through the HKU's with the following code, but I'd like to handle the uninstallation completely via Inno Setup and not have to call into a separate executable on uninstall.

```csharp
private static string GetSIDFromUserName(string userName)
{
    var account = new System.Security.Principal.NTAccount(userName);
    var identifier = (System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier)account.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
    var sid = identifier.Value;
    return sid;
}

private static string[] GetAllSystemUsers()
{
    List<string> names = new List<string>();
    SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount");
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get())
    {
        names.Add((string)envVar["Name"]);
    }
    return names.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete an autorun entry from all users, use:

```pascal
procedure DeleteAutoRunEntryFromAllUsers(AutoRunValueName: string);
var
  Names: TArrayOfString;
  UserKey: string;
  AutoRunKey: string;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Log('Enumerating user keys');
  RegGetSubkeyNames(HKEY_USERS, '', Names);
  Log(Format('Found %d user keys', [GetArrayLength(Names)]));

  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Names)-1 do
  begin
    UserKey := Names[I];
    Log(Format('User %s', [UserKey]));
    AutoRunKey := Format('%s\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', [UserKey]);

    if RegValueExists(HKEY_USERS, AutoRunKey, AutoRunValueName) then
    begin
      Log(Format('Deleting auto-run entry from user %s', [UserKey]));

      if RegDeleteValue(HKEY_USERS, AutoRunKey, AutoRunValueName) then
      begin
        Log(Format('Deleted auto-run entry from user %s', [UserKey]));
      end
        else
      begin
        Log(Format('Failed to delete auto-run entry from user %s', [UserKey]));
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

Not sure about the roaming profiles.

---

Did you consider adding the autorun entry to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, but make the application to exit immediately based on a setting in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (per user preference)?

This way you could just uninstall a single `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` value. The setting in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` might be left behind.

Comment: Your final suggestion might work for the auto-run entry might work, but I also install an explorer context menu extension. That should also be a per-user option, and you can't just pretend its not there, like you suggest with the auto-run. How is this implemented in WinSCP?

Comment: The extension is typically registered machine-wide in HKLM.

Comment: this just doesn't work for me, deleting the registry ONLY for administrator, but leaving all the other users' registry as is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us a log or anything!