# Can't get Inno Setup postinstall Run item to runasoriginaluser

Tags: inno-setup

I am testing an Inno Setup in Windows 10.
I have `PrivilegesRequired=lowest`

In the `[Run]` section with `postinstall` I launch an Excel workbook.
This workbook makes changes to the Excel environment for the user that launched Excel.
By default, that user is the standard user, which is what I want.
But if run with right-click elevated privilege, that user is the admin user.
How can I force Excel to launch for the standard user?

I tried the flags `runasoriginaluser` and `runascurrentuser`, but neither of these would force Excel to run for the standard user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you explicitly run the installer as Administrator, there's no way to access the user session. (Note that it's not an Inno Setup limitation, it's how Windows works.)

All you can do is to detect the Administrator privileges and notify the user not run the installer as Administrator.

```pascal
[Code]

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  if (GetWindowsVersion >= $05010000) and
     IsAdminLoggedOn then
  begin
    MsgBox('Do not run this installer "As Administrator".', mbError, MB_OK);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

For details, see [Installing application for currently logged in user from Inno Setup installer running as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44575666/850848).