# Determine if Administrator account that runs elevated Inno Setup installer is the same as the account of the current Windows logon session

Tags: inno-setup

I am using `PrivilegesRequired=lowest` in my Inno Setup script.  If setup is running elevated, i.e. `IsAdminLoggedOn or IsPowerUserLoggedOn` reports TRUE, how can I determine if the elevated user account is the same account from which setup was launched?

My script can do different things accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`WTSQuerySessionInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationw) to retrieve an account username for the current Windows logon session.

```pascal
function WTSQuerySessionInformation(
  hServer: THandle; SessionId: Cardinal; WTSInfoClass: Integer;
  var pBuffer: DWord; var BytesReturned: DWord): Boolean;
  external 'WTSQuerySessionInformationW@wtsapi32.dll stdcall';

procedure WTSFreeMemory(pMemory: DWord);
  external 'WTSFreeMemory@wtsapi32.dll stdcall';

procedure RtlMoveMemoryAsString(Dest: string; Source: DWord; Len: Integer);
  external 'RtlMoveMemory@kernel32.dll stdcall';

const
  WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = 0;
  WTS_CURRENT_SESSION = -1;
  WTSUserName = 5;

function GetCurrentSessionUserName: string;
var
  Buffer: DWord;
  BytesReturned: DWord;
  QueryResult: Boolean;
begin
  QueryResult :=
    WTSQuerySessionInformation(
      WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, WTSUserName, Buffer,
      BytesReturned);

  if not QueryResult then
  begin
    Log('Failed to retrieve username');
    Result := '';
  end
    else
  begin
    SetLength(Result, (BytesReturned div 2) - 1);
    RtlMoveMemoryAsString(Result, Buffer, BytesReturned);
    WTSFreeMemory(Buffer);
    Log(Format('Retrieved username "%s"', [Result]));
  end;
end;
```

*(The code is for [Unicode version of Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43158677/850848) – The only version as of Inno Setup 6).*

---

You can then compare the result against [`GetUserNameString`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getusernamestring).

---

*You may need to add a domain name into the comparison.*

Comment: The INNO help documentation for GetUserNameString says "Retrieves the name of the user currently logged onto the system." But it's really more like "Retrieves the name of the user for which setup is running."

Comment: Thanks. For both version support (ansi/unicode):
#ifdef UNICODE
  external 'WTSQuerySessionInformationW@wtsapi32.dll stdcall';
#else
  external 'WTSQuerySessionInformationA@wtsapi32.dll stdcall';
#endif
and:
#ifdef UNICODE
  SetLength(Result, (BytesReturned div 2) - 1);
#else
 SetLength(Result, (BytesReturned) - 1);
#endif

Comment: @carlos Thanks for sharing this. Though everyone should really use Unicode version.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the full account name of the current user (e.g., *authority*`\`*username* format), you can use the **GetUserNameExW** Windows API function. The below snippet demonstrates how to call this function from Inno Setup:

```
const
  ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;

function GetUserNameExW(NameFormat: Integer; lpNameBuffer: string; var nSize: DWORD): Boolean;
  external 'GetUserNameExW@secur32.dll stdcall';

function GetFullUserName(): string;
var
  NumChars: DWORD;
  OutStr: string;
begin
  result := '';
  NumChars := 0;
  if (not GetUserNameExW(2, '', NumChars)) and (DLLGetLastError() = ERROR_MORE_DATA) then
  begin
    SetLength(OutStr, NumChars);
    if GetUserNameExW(2, OutStr, NumChars) then
      result := Copy(OutStr, 1, NumChars);
  end;
end;
```

(The value `2` passed to the first parameter (`NameFormat`) in the **GetUserNameExW** function corresponds to `NameSamCompatible` in the `EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT` enumeration.)