# Create a folder in AppData in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I need to create a folder called `WindowsExplorerCmd` with a file called `CmdXdll.dll` in `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming` (`{userappdata}`) folder.

How to?

Answer (score 4):

To create a standalone empty directory, use [`[Dirs]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=dirssection) entry like:

```
[Dirs]
Name: {userappdata}\WindowsExplorerCmd
```

---

Though you rarely need this. A folder typically gets implicitly created when installing files using [`[Files]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection):

```
[Files]
Source: "CmdXdll.dll"; DestDir: "{userappdata}\WindowsExplorerCmd"
```

---

Note that for `{user*}` constants (like `{userappdata}`) to work reliably, you need to run the installer in non-Administrator mode ([`PrivilegesRequired`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired) set to `lowest`). Otherwise you may not get the behavior you want. See also [Installing application for currently logged in user from Inno Setup installer running as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44575666/850848).