# programmatically pin to quick access for another (or all) user

Tags: inno-setup, powershell-4.0, windows-10-iot-enterprise

using inno-setup, so if there's a better way, please say so.

I've got a powershell command that will pin a dir to the quick access. something like:
`(new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace("D:\").Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome")`
or I can use a shellGuid instead of `"D:\"`

the actual line I'm using (in an inno function) is:

```
Exec('cmd.exe', '/C powershell.exe -command "(new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace(\"D:\\\").Self.InvokeVerb(\"pintohome\")"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

However, this only adds it for the current user, and when inno is running, that's the admin user. It's for a device that runs in kiosk mode, so I  need this to be effective for the 'normal' user (or for all users would be just fine).

any ideas?

I have seen and read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44575666/850848), please notice this question is *not* about trying to install an application for somebody else, this could, presumably, be solved with a carefully crafted reg file, or other minor manipulation. This is making a change for all users, or for a group of users that affects the quick access, this has *nothing* to do with installing an entire application for a separate user

Comment: Start here: [Installing application for currently logged in user from Inno Setup installer running as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44575666/850848)

Comment: Did you **read** my answer to the linked question? It covers even the *"change for all users"*.

Comment: if I infer what you're suggesting, is it that I set a custom batch file (or similar) to run on first login for each user where the batch file does the quick access pinning that I want?  If that's the idea you're getting at, it may be able to work.  However nothing here makes my question a duplicate; perhaps an inference from your above-and-beyond answer can answer my question, but that chain of events doesn't make my question a duplicate of the other.

Comment: That's the only correct solution. -- There are other ways too (described in the middle section of my answer).

Comment: Regarding the duplicity: What part of your question is not covered by my answer?